# How to check registry path available or not using WIX installer

Tags: .net, wix, vsto, outlook-addin, wix3.5

I am working with VSTO Outlook addin. I have to find the version outlook which is installed and then have to set some registry value.
I have to set **Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences** one DWord value if outlook16 present and if outlook13 is present then need to set **Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Preferences** one value.
I have to check that in If Else, I am not getting how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply read check which version(s) of the registry key is present (15 vs 16 vs something else) and set it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [RegLocator](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/read_a_registry_entry.html) table and configure it to set the value into a Windows installer Property then condition your Feature on that property value.